# Question about time behaviour of capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

Looking at the following circuit:
[image]

What would happen right after S is closed and what happens after a while of running?

My idea is that right after closing there will be a short-circuit like behaviour, where there is almost no voltage difference on C. With time the voltage over C increases, which when the capacitor is fully loaded all voltage will fall off over C and all current passes through R. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

It's a somewhat "pathological" circuit: a capacitor connected directly to a pure voltage source.

The capacitor charges instantly with an infinite current peak (Dirac pulse). The current in the resistor immediately takes the value $U/R$

Comment: Would that also be the case for long after S was closed?

Comment: With this circuit, there is no further evolution once the switch is closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example for the limits of an approximation. If you do this in the real world, then you will find that there are no ideal voltage sources: in reality all voltage sources have an internal resistance that limits the current.

You will also find that "wires" in a circuit diagram are not representing actual physical wires. They are the edges of a mathematical graph that describes the circuit in Kirchhoff approximation, i.e. by assuming energy and charge conservation.

While charge conservation is usually a correct assumption, unless there is arcing or something heats up so much that it causes thermoelectric emission, energy conservation is not true in reality because the current through a loop of finite area builds up a magnetic field that together with the electric field around the wire forms an electromagnetic dipole field. In other words, the real circuit would start to oscillate at a high frequency (given roughly by the square root of the product of the loop inductance and the capacitance) and it would lose energy to free space in form of electromagnetic radiation. This would limit the current as well.

As always in physics we try to make a problem as simple as possible, but not simpler. So for the purposes of this circuit it's a good idea to bypass the transient analysis and to assume that the capacitor has been charged to the voltage of the voltage source, already. At that point the description of the circuit is complete enough to solve it. If we wanted to do the transient analysis in addition, then we would have to know more about the circuit: in first order we would need the internal resistance of the voltage source and the total loop inductance. In higher order there is no stopping: we would have to specify the three dimensional geometry and all the material properties of the metals, the resistor's material and the capacitor's dielectric and then we would have to solve Maxwell's equations on that geometry. That's a really, really hard problem which is usually done with some rather expensive and hard to use numerical software.